# Function to build a line to retrieve data from json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm writing a function that takes arguments and add them to form a line to look for data in a JSON file. I've defined a variable for the `readFileSync` and the add to it the arguments of the function to look for the data.

```js
var jf = require('jsonfile'),
    file = 'logins.json',
    i = 1;

var jsonData = jf.readFileSync(file);

function getJSONData() {
  var n = 1;
  var com = '';

  do {
    if (arguments[n] !== undefined) {
      com += `['${arguments[n]}']`;
    }

    n++;
  } while (n < arguments.length);

  return com;
}

var h = getJSONData(i, 'operator', 'id');

console.log(jsonData[i] + h);
```

This is my JSON:

```js
[
  {
    "operator": {
      "id": "avalle",
      "pass": "Aa123456",
      "something": "idk",
      "account": [
        {
          "type": "asd",
          "idk": "asd"
        },
        {
          "type": "asd",
          "idk": "asd"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "operator": {
      "id": "oleal",
      "pass": "Aa123456",
      "something": "idk",
      "account": [
        {
          "type": "asd",
          "idk": "asd"
        },
        {
          "type": "asd",
          "idk": "asd"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I should get a line of `jsonData[i]['param1']['param2']` that locates the data in the file.

Instead i get `undefined` or `[object Object]['operador']['id']`

Comment: The `readFileSync` function returns a string or buffer. You need to turn it into JSON before you can access it by index.

Comment: if you want the exact string `jsonData[i][operator][id]` you need to treat jsonData[i] as a string instead of a variable. `console.log('jsonData[i]' + h)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a property to be returned from the function you can make this change:

```
function getJSONData(jsonData) {
  var n = 1;
  var result = jsonData;

  do {
    if (result[arguments[n]]) {
      result = result[arguments[n]]
    } else {
        console.error(`Property ${arguments[n]} does not exist on obj:`, result)
    }

    n++;
  } while (n < arguments.length);

  return result;
}

var h = getJSONData(jsonData[i], 'operator', 'id');
```

Otherwise you return a string from `getJSONData` that looks like `"[prop1][prop2]"` and it will not retrieve a property by trying to concat Object + string